# Comparing corresponding values of two lines in a file using awk

Tags: awk

```
name1   20160801|76 20160802|67 20160803|49 20160804|35 20160805|55 20160806|76 20160807|77 20160808|70 2016089|50  20160810|75 20160811|97 20160812|90 20160813|87 20160814|99 20160815|113    20160816|83 20160817|57 20160818|158    20160819|61 20160820|46 20160821|1769608    20160822|2580938    20160823|436093 20160824|75 20160825|57 20160826|70 20160827|97 20160828|101    20160829|96 20160830|95 20160831|89 
name2   20160801|32413  20160802|37707  20160803|32230  20160804|31711  20160805|32366  20160806|35532  20160807|36961  20160808|45423  2016089|65230   20160810|111078 20160811|74357  20160812|71196  20160813|71748  20160814|77001  20160815|91687  20160816|92076  20160817|89706  20160818|126690 20160819|168587 20160820|207128 20160821|221440 20160822|234594 20160823|200963 20160824|165231 20160825|139600 20160826|145483 20160827|209013 20160828|228550 20160829|223712 20160830|217959 20160831|169106
```

I have the line position of two lines in a file say line1 and line2. These lines may be anywhere in the file but I can access the line position using a search keyword based on name(the first word) in each line

20160801 means yyyymmdd and has an associated value separated by |
I need to compare  the values associated with each of the date for the given two lines.

I am a newbie in awk. I am not understanding how to compare these two lines at the same time.

Comment: I am not understanding. 1) Are `name1` and `name2` unique values for each file? i.e., more than 1 of these per file? Do you just need to find name1 in file 1 and name2 in file 2 and compare the date string in each line?

Comment: name 1 name2 is going to be unique throughout the file. Each line has 31 days. Next to day is pipe sepearted value for that day. I need to compare the corresponding values for the days in both line. Each line has 31 days of a given month.So the dates and their position is same in the file

Comment: compare and do what?  What is your expected output?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/39544790/1745001? How about providing some feedback on the multiple answers you received to that question before opening an apparently identical one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not at all clear. Perhaps the first step is to clearly articulate 1) What is the problem I am trying to solve; 2) what tools or data do I have to solve it?

The only hints specific to your question I can offer (since your problem statement is not clearly articulated) are these:

1. In awk, you can compare two different files by using the test `FNR==NR` which is only true on the first file.
2. You can find the key words by using a regular expression of the form `/^name1/` which means lines that start with that pattern
3. You can split on a delimiter in awk by setting the field separator to that delimiter -- in this case (I think) it sounds like that is `|` but you are also comparing white space delimited fields inside of those fields?
4. You can compare by saving the data from the first line and comparing with the data from the second line in the other file once you can articulate what 'compare' means to you.

Wrapping that up, given:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
name1   20160801|76 20160802|67 20160803|49 20160804|35 20160805|55 20160806|76 20160807|77 20160808|70 2016089|50  20160810|75 20160811|97 20160812|90 20160813|87 20160814|99 20160815|113    20160816|83 20160817|57 20160818|158    20160819|61 20160820|46 20160821|1769608    20160822|2580938    20160823|436093 20160824|75 20160825|57 20160826|70 20160827|97 20160828|101    20160829|96 20160830|95 20160831|89 
$ cat /tmp/f2.txt
name2   20160801|32413  20160802|37707  20160803|32230  20160804|31711  20160805|32366  20160806|35532  20160807|36961  20160808|45423  2016089|65230   20160810|111078 20160811|74357  20160812|71196  20160813|71748  20160814|77001  20160815|91687  20160816|92076  20160817|89706  20160818|126690 20160819|168587 20160820|207128 20160821|221440 20160822|234594 20160823|200963 20160824|165231 20160825|139600 20160826|145483 20160827|209013 20160828|228550 20160829|223712 20160830|217959 20160831|169106
```

You can find the lines in question like so:

```
$ awk -F"|" '/^name/ && FNR==NR {print $1}' f1.txt f2.txt
name1   20160801
$ awk -F"|" '/^name/ && FNR<NR {print $1}' f1.txt f2.txt
name2   20160801
```

(I have only printed the first field for clarity)

Then use that to compare. Save the first in an associative array and then compare the second when found.